# How to grant all privileges in one line to a created user on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, command-line-interface

I have been using PostgreSQL for quite few months now and I was wondering if there is anyway I could grant all users privilege to a new user without having to give roles one at the time. If anyone could help with the correct syntax I will be completely grateful. This is what I tried

```
ALTER USER Faouzi WITH SUPERUSER CREATE_ROLE CREATE_DB REPLICATION BYPASS_RLS ;
```

Comment: I mean list of roles attributes. for example when you type \du in psql you will see a table with all available users and their roles attributes.

Comment: landfreight=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 faouzi    | Superuser                                                  | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

Comment: what I mean is how to give a new user multiple roles with a single command in psql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is slighly off. It is `CREATEDB` and `CREATEROLE`. Besides, if you are superuser, you have everything else automatically.

So this is enough:

```
ALTER ROLE faouzi SUPERUSER;
```